# How to draw shapes in a graph using nodes and edges in python?

Tags: python, graph, shapes

I need to draw the shapes from the following photo in a graph. I need to transpose the shapes in a graph in Python with nodes and edges. [img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HHJM.png)

[image: img2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the standard tools for defining graphs like this is the [DOT language](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html) used by [Graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/).

You can create DOT graph descriptions and render them with the PyPI package [graphviz](https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/), or with the [pydot package](https://github.com/pydot/pydot).

Both appear to require that you have Graphviz installed if you want to render images.

Disclaimer: I've written plenty of Python and I've fiddled with DOT and Graphviz, but I haven't used the above libraries.